# How does mobile Gmail's page transition work?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, css-animations

I'm really liking the mobile Gmail's quite smooth page transitions, https://mail.google.com/mail/mu.

Does anyone know how they do this? Is there a library they use?

I had a look around myself but it wasn't obvious. A hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code it seems they're doing this with CSS3 transitions. Specifically

```
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1000ms;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: initial;
-webkit-transition-delay: initial;
```

Here's the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/

Here's some info on how they work: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understanding-css3-transitions/

Comment: You're right, it would seem so. Although, I should have said, I was referring to the 'sliding'-effects seen when visiting the site on a mobile device. But I suppose that's done with the same `-webkit-transition` method. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh - OK. I'd say without a doubt they're using 3D transforms (specifically a "translate"). 3D transforms can be hardware accelerated - hence the smoothness. Only webkit browsers support this. Here's an article which explains it quite nicely: http://googlecode.blogspot.co.nz/2010/08/css3-transitions-and-transforms-in.html